# For loop to write ANOVA results in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write the summaries of multiple ANOVA runs, stored in a list, to a CSV file.

```
for(i in anova_results) {
output = summary(anova_results[[i]])
form = sprintf('anovaresult_%s.csv', i)
capture.output(output, file = form)
}
```

However, upon doing some I'm getting an error on the 'subscript type':

```
Error in anova_results[[i]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Upon searching this error, I can't seem to figure out why this loop won't work.

Comment: I think you need `for(i in seq_along(anova_results))` i.e. loop over the sequence of the `list`, then the code should work.  Also, change the `%s` to `%d` in `sprintf`